# Creating a matrix based on 3 inputs

Tags: python, function, matrix

I need to create a 2 by `n` matrix

```
    x   y
1  x1  y1
2  x2  y2
3  x3  y3
4  x4  y4
5  x5  y5
.  ..  ..
n  xn  yn
```

it needs to be created from a function with 3 inputs: `x`,`y`, and `n`, let us call it `make_m(x,y,n)`

the matrix needs to follow this criteria:

1. the sum of the numbers in column x = `x`
2. the sum of the numbers in column y = `y`
3. in any given row, x#/y# = `x/y`
4. there must be `n` number of rows

now I have a function that will find all the possible pairs of `x` and `y` and return them in a list of tuples, but I have no clue how to approach the question of finding which tuples to to put as the rows to satisfy the 4 requirements. Here is that function:

```
def find_r(x,y):
   return [(a, a*num2/num1) for a in range(1, num1) if (a*num2) % num1 == 0]
```

yes, there will be some examples that wont work because of the ratio, for example:

```
In [60]: find_r(100,891)
Out[60]: []
```

And there will be some that just simply wont work for certain numbers of `n`. For example the following will not be possible for values of `n` higher than 4

```
In [57]: find_r(100,364)
Out[57]: [(25, 91), (50, 182), (75, 273)]
```

But do not worry about those for now.

the real issue is that many resulting possibilities have a large amount of possibilities, so I not only need an algorithmic function to pick out the correct tuples, but the best tuples.

I would like it such that the tuples it picks are as close to each other in size if possible, meaning that the best solution is that of which only one tuple is repeated for the entire sequence.

So how can I write a function that will be able to create the matrix that I need?

Comment: What kind of numbers are allowed? Positive integers? Negative integers? Real numbers?

Comment: I can't see any number other than `1` that satisfies your formula.

Comment: @Humungus only real, positive integers. This will eventually be applied to a situation where the numbers `x` and `y` are sizes of arrays. @Meitham Maybe I was unclear, what do you thing the "formula" is?

Answer (score 2):

What could help you is finding the [Greatest common divisor (GCD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) of `x` and `y`. It will tell you what is the maximum `n` that still yields a result, and also help you in finding the rows of the matrix.

If you divide both `x` and `y` by their GCD, you will get the lowest combination of `x#` and `y#` that satisfies the ratio requirement.. Let's denote it as `z`. Now you need to find `n` numbers from 1 to the GCD whose sum equals the GCD. These numbers indicate what multiples of `z` to use as rows of the matrix.

**Example**:
I will use your list for `x = 100`, `y = 364`

```
In [57]: find_r(100,364)
Out[57]: [(25, 91), (50, 182), (75, 273)]
```

with `n` = 2.

GCD(100, 364) = 4. So in this case, `z` = (25, 91). With `n` = 2, we need two numbers between 1 and 4 that add up to 4. This gives us two combinations: Either 2, 2 *(using these to multiply `z` we get two pairs of numbers: [(50, 182),(50, 182)])* or 1, 3 *([(25, 91), (75, 273)])*.

For `n` = 3, the only solution would be 1, 1, 2; and for `n` = 4 just 1, 1, 1, 1. Any higher `n` wouldn't yield any result.

I hope this helps. Also, it expects that you can only use positive integers - the task would become trivial with negative ones.